# VS2015 SQLite provider not showing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I am having an issue and I'm pulling my hair out. I am running on a 64-bit machine, and I want to use SQLite. I installed the x64 version of SQLite, the 4.6 .NET Framework version (as my project is in 4.6 in VS2015). I added System.Data.SQLite.dll, System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll, and .../SQLite.Linq.dll as references in the project. I have the EntityFramework (>version 6, so it's fine) as a reference too. However, when I go to add a new connection, I do not see SQLite as a provider. I've looked everywhere and I just can not find the answer. Please, I am losing my sanity.

EDIT: Well even though I couldn't select it in a new connection, I was able to manually create and open a connection in the code behind with

SQLiteConnection mConn = new SQLiteConnection("myPathToDatabase");
mConn.Open();

Then eventually closing it when the window closes. I also managed to set up a reader and replaced all the SQL Server/ LINQ to SQL code I had.
I still would like to know how to get it set up in the new connections window, but it's not as important now.

Comment: I don't know why but the formatting wasn't working in that edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you chose the correct download for SQLite.  I think you downloaded one of the packages that contains the runtime components, but not the design-time components.  If you go to the [download page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), you'll see that one of the packages is marked "**This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2015.**"  (Emphasis theirs.)

Try downloading that package, and good luck!

Comment: That was the first thing I tried :P Whatever, I got it to work without the design-time part, both on the main machine and my laptop, so I'll just leave it how it is. Thanks :)

Comment: Rats, oh well.  Personally I always do it the manual way, so I don't need the design-time components.  It would be nice to have them available though!